# Logarithm of a negative number in a very special case.

Tags: complex-numbers

It is stated that:-

$\log_b(n)$ is undefined, if  $n < 0 $.

However,

$\log_i(-1) = 2$, $i$ represents the imaginary number.

Here, $-1 <0$, but the operation is well defined.

**My question:-**

Is the logarithm of a negative number well defined only if base is an imaginary number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Short answer: No. The logarithm is defined for all complex numbers not equal to zero.

In complex analysis, the definition of $\log z$ where $z$ is a complex number not equal to zero, is $\log z=\log |z| +i\arg z$, where $\arg z$ gives the angle in the complex plane. Clearly, this reduces to the regular definition for $z>0$.

So, $\log_i (-1)=\log(-1)/\log (i)$; using our formula, $\log(-1)=\log(1)+i\pi$, and $\log(i)=\log(1)+i\pi/2$, giving us your result.